# Is there an Alfred Workflow to install and view Alfred workflows?

Tags: automation, productivity, alfred

I want a workflow like the [cask / brew workflow](http://www.packal.org/workflow/homebrew-and-cask-alfred) for Alfred workflows. Does this already exists?

e.g. auto completion, viewing and installing and removing right from alfred instead of searching google to find and install and the preferences to remove.

Answer (score 1):

There are websites like http://alfredworkflow.com and [Packal](http://www.packal.org) which have hundreds of available workflows which you can download for free.

There is **Workflow Searcher** Alfred Workflow which lets you find and install alfred workflows available on http://www.alfredworkflow.com/ from within Alfred itself. which you can download from [here](https://github.com/hzlzh/Alfred-Workflows/raw/master/Downloads/Workflow-Searcher.alfredworkflow)

There is also [awm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/awm) (Alfred Workflow Manager) which lets you find and install workflow found on [Packal](http://www.packal.org) using the terminal. It requires you to have **node** and the node package manager **npm** installed.